# Users and Groups No Save Button

Tags: users, privileges

I am trying to add User Privileges; Use modems & Connect to wireless & ethernet networks to my current & only user profile.

It'll ask for my password & I am admin, but the save/cancel buttons are completely missing from opened window.

I am running a fresh install of Xubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

It saves automatically, so no need for an Apply button in this case.

Comment: Well I re-enter settings & both boxes are deselected/unticked again, so not my experience I'm afraid...